# Keyboard backlight is very dim

Tags: fedora, keyboard, samsung, keyboard-backlight

I have a Samsung Series 9 running Fedora. It has a backlit keyboard but even at the maximum setting, keys are not readable.

The functions keys controlling the level are working, the OSD indicator pops up and looks fine, but all my online searches lead to tutorials on fixing the function keys.

The exact machine looks like a Christmas tree under Windows XP/7/8.

How can I fix this thing?

Comment: probably you don't have a driver for it

Comment: I have a samsung_laptop module loaded